# Need to find counts of values stored in multiple colums

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to be able to count the number of times a particular value appears in a column based on another column in a table. Below is the sample table:

```
Color   Shape       Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5
--------------------------------------------------------
Blue    Circle      Blue    Null    Yellow  Null    Null
Blue    Circle      Blue    Null    Null    Null    Black
Blue    Circle      Null    Null    Null    Null    Null
Yellow  Square      Null    Null    Null    Null    Null
Yellow  Square      Null    Yellow  Null    Null    Null
Yellow  Square      Null    Null    Null    Null    Null
Yellow  Square      Green   Null    Null    Yellow  Null
Yellow  Square      Null    Null    Null    Null    Null
Green   Rectangle   Null    Null    Null    Null    Green
Orange  Triangle    Gray    White   Null    Null    Orange
Orange  Triangle    Null    Orange  Null    Null    Null
```

I need the result to be the below table:

```
Color   Shape      Col1 Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5
----------------------------------------------------
Blue    Circle      2   0       0       0       0
Yellow  Square      0   1       0       1       0
Green   Rectangle   0   0       0       0       1
Orange  Triangle    0   1       0       0       1
```

This query is not giving me the desire out:

```
select 
    Color, Shape, 
    count(Col1) as Col1, count(Col2) as Col2, 
    count(Col3) as Col3, count(Col4) as Col4, count(Col5) as Col5
from 
    Sample_Table 
group by 
    Color, Shape
```

Does anyone know how to get the desire output?

Comment: Your query seems fine to me. Count should ignore null values. can you post the dml + ddl for the sample table?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, the OP wants to count only columns where the content is the same as column `Color`... The existing query would return all counts of columns `NOT NULL`...

Comment: @Shnugo: Apparently you are correct and I've misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `CASE` expressions to do conditional counting:

```
select 
    Color, Shape, 
    count(case when Color = Col1 then 1 end) as Col1, 
    count(case when Color = Col2 then 1 end) as Col2, 
    count(case when Color = Col3 then 1 end) as Col3, 
    count(case when Color = Col4 then 1 end) as Col4, 
    count(case when Color = Col5 then 1 end) as Col5 
from 
    Sample_Table 
group by 
    Color, Shape
```

Comment: You were faster than me :-) +1 from my side